# Why Visual Studio 2013 propose saving file in saving file dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, file, save

Sometimes when I've change some file and type Ctrl+S, Visual Studio 2013 Professional doesn't save it in normal way but propose me Save this file as... in Save File Dialog and then in folder with my file appears another file like xjxklb2q.10h or brq1p3lm.0gi. Anybody knows what is going on?

Comment: Is the file read only or perhaps some disassembly?

Answer (score 0):

I'd log a bug to Visual Studio. If you look in the top right corner there's a smiley face that allows you to "send a frown" - just describe what you were doing and it will be picked up by someone in the platform team.